# Apigility InputFilter injection

Tags: laminas-api-tools

Given I am posting to an endpoint as so:

POST http://foo.com/user/:user_id/articles

```
{
  "content": "some text"
}
```

when I configure the Validator within the config I am struggling to find how to inject the :user_id from the route along with the "content" from the body. So my Validator is stuck trying to validate if "content" is ok without the :user_id.

What is the proper Apigility way to inject IDs (or even ideally objects) from route parameters into the Validator(s) along with the normal body $data payload?

Many thanks

Comment: You can create your own filter, and do whatever processing you want there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, apigility has no way to validate the route parameters.
Personally i validate them in de resource or the controller.
That way i can do some more complex validation, like does this id exist?

If you want an object as a route parameter, you van try serializing the object and putting that in your parameter.
But i would advice against this. Would you even trust an external party to provide you with whole objects?
If you need some user info you could look into JWT or similar techniques.
JWT is a authorisation token that also contains any data (it's json based).

Now, any body params can be validated.
In the apigility ui, you can go to fields, and add the fields you want to validate there (or it should be all of them for simplicity).
Then you can assign filters and validators here. Even custom ones you have configured in your zf2 application.

Comment: Unfortunately, as mentioned above, apigility won't apply filters to query string parameters, you need to handle those manually.

Comment: Yes, that is correct and unfortunatly.
It could be extended tough to filter those as well.